# Acer/Windows 7 Not connecting to wifi on specific network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

My computer won't connect to my school network via wifi, I'm able to plug it into a port to connect, but it won't connect with the wifi. Well, it connects to the wifi, and says its connected to the internet, but the internet isn't working. I've been to other places with wifi with my computer and it works fine, its just here. It happened after a got a notification about my IP address or something was about to change, and did I want to let that happen, I hit block because I had 5 seconds to think about it before it just let it happen. I don't know if this has any correlation or not. I didn't care so much because I'm graduating in 3 weeks, but I have to use campus wifi tomorrow and so I need to fix this now. Any ideas on what the problem could be? All my network drivers are up to date. What can I do?

Comment: Good. You found it. Sorry if I sounded rude before. Try opening CMD and running `ipconfig /release` and then `ipconfig /renew`.

Comment: No its fine, I understand, thank you. That did not work. It said it can't do anything while media is disconnected

Comment: Did it return to a prompt? If not, that's just the ethernet card saying that. If the WiFi is connected, it will renew its IP.

Comment: Had to post it in the answer section because it was too long, but that was everything that came up before it went back to the prompt

Comment: You should be able to use the internet. Your WiFi adapter has an IP now.

Comment: What else could be wrong because its not working, I still have to plug in to connect, when I try to access youtube, just the first site I tried, it says unable to connect and has this message DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software installed? If so, what is it?

Comment: Avast free, I regularly scan with advanced system care 8, malwarebytes, and crapcleaner

Comment: Do any of them have network controls?

Comment: There's network security, but to my knowledge there's no control over my connectivity to the network. However, I have very basic knowledge of networks I'm sorry to say.

Comment: and just avast is always running for antivirus, the others are just running whenever I decide to scan

Comment: Try exiting Avast and trying to connect to the internet again.

Comment: Is your school's name Mercy Hurst?

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Follow these instructions to add `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.8.4` to your DNS: http://www.opennicproject.org/configure-your-dns/how-to-change-dns-servers-in-windows-7/

Comment: What will that do?

Comment: Well, it looks like you're not getting a DNS server address from the network, for whatever reason. This will add Google's DNS servers to your list, letting the computer use them when the primary address fails.

Comment: Oh my god it worked!

Comment: Good! I'll make it into an answer, with real instructions.

Comment: I'm going to convert the comment into an answer. Click the check mark below the votes to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our comment discussion:

It looks like you aren't getting a DNS address from your school's network, for some strange reason. Adding Google's DNS addresses should fix this. Here's how to add them (Windows 7 and later):

1. Open the Start Menu/Screen and search `View Network Connections`.
2. Right-click on your WiFi adapter and select `Properties`.
3. Double-click the `Internet Protocol Version 4` option, then click `Advanced` (bottom right).
4. Go to the `DNS` tab and click the `Add...` button under the first box.
5. Input `8.8.8.8` into the dialog box that comes up and click `Add`.
6. Repeat step 5, but replace the address with `8.8.8.4`.

That should (and did) do it.